# Sum of Powers of two Integers using only For-Loops

Tags: java, for-loop

The question here would be to get the sum of powers (m^0 + m^1 + m^2 + m^3.... + m^n) using only FOR loops. Meaning, not using any other loops as well as Math.pow();

Is it even possible? So far, I am only able to work around getting m^n, but not the rest.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total  = 1;

    System.out.print("Enter value of m: ");
    int m = scn.nextInt(); 
    System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
    int n = scn.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){   
        total * m;
        }
    System.out.print(total);
}
```

Let's say m =8; and n = 4;

i gives me '1,2,3,4' which is what I need, but I am unable to power m ^ i.

Would be nice if someone could guide me into how it could be done, can't seem to progress onwards as I have limited knowledge in Java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to rewrite it like this :

```
m^0 + m^1 + m^2 + m^3.... + m^n = 1 + m * (1 + m * (1 + m * (.... ) ) )
```

And you do it in a single for loop.

This should do the job (see explanations in comments):

```
public long count(long m, int pow) {
  long result = 1;
  for(int i = 0;i<pow; i++) {
    result*=m +1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: One thing that's not necessarily obvious: the algoritm would work from the inside-out. (So it's uh... `for i = 0 to n: result = result * m + 1`, starting with `result = 1`?)

Comment: You must take it reversely (from the most bracketed expression) : begin with `m`. At each step, you muliply by `m` and add 1.

Comment: That's what I meant "from the inside out". You start at the innermost level of nesting. Also clearly you don't begin with `m` because for `n = 0`, the result should be `1`, and for `n = 1`, the result should be `m + 1`. My loop above might have an off-by-one error (as in either `i = 0 to n` or `i = 1 to n` is correct), but I'm certain starting at `1` is correct.

Comment: The equality between these 2 statements is not trivial.

Comment: When you see it for the first time, no. But this is a classic IT school exercise to learn how to reduce complexity.

Comment: @Cruncher Sorry, but the equivalency is pretty damn simple for anyone who had freshman college-level maths. As in, the first thing to do when you see a sum of terms that all start with the same variable is to see what happens when you factorise it.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest loops. Use one to compute the powers and another to sum them.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Usually I would, but this looks like a homework so I do not want to give a complete answer. A hint is more useful.

Comment: @kiheru Since homework questions aren't really considered special (anymore), another way of looking at your answer is that you're being deliberately coy and abstruse. (Of course in the end it's the votes that matter.)

Comment: By not providing the answer you will encourage reposts from other people who google for their problem and come to this page but only get this hint. That's why I prefer to always add code; the poster did put some effort in it. That's just my opinion though, I'm not entirely sure about the official guidelines to this.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The assignment is surely not to try, not get it, then have someone else give you the code. However try, not get it, ask for help, get a hint, figure it out. This seems perfectly fair.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The official guidelines are that the question should stand on its own merit, and the answer should as well. IMO both are dubious in this case which is why I've not voted either way on both. The question is dubious since it's not a practical programming problem: the "do not use `Math.pow()` restriction is contrived. The answer is dubious because it's the least amount of content possible to at all qualify as an answer to the question. tl;dr: it's a meh answer to a meh question, hence: meh.

Comment: @Cruncher: the fact that it's homework is irrelevant though. If he would have specified that he's doing this to test himself and got stuck everyone would be happy to provide code. He should be old enough to be smart about it and put in his best effort, but we're also here to help future browsers.

Comment: @Cruncher It's not in the mandate of SO to enforce academic honesty. You're certainly free to do so when answering questions, but for myself I agree with the [arguments that lead to the death](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) of [tag:homework]. The whole second-guessing the asker and "leading" them to the answer also seems more like an annoying power-trip than a genuine didactic technique. (It's kind of like those annoying lateral thinking puzzles that hinge mostly on whether you've heard that one before.)

Comment: @Cruncher Furthermore, slowly feeding someone hints as a teaching aid doesn't really seem as suited to the QA format as it is to a classroom where you can actually interact with the student and find out which of the concepts involved they're struggling with. (That said, IANATeacher. Grain of salt etc.) Also, another general rule-of-thumb of SO applies: when you find yourself posting a bad answer, you should take a second look at the question.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. I'm actually looking for such an answer instead of just codes (which I might never learn at all).

As a result, I said something like "Would be nice if someone could guide me into how it could be done" instead of "Give me the codes".

Comment: Oh and this isn't a homework, this is just practice questions on Nested For-Loops that I got from my friend. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can do below:

```
int mul = 1;
total = 1;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    mul *= m;
    total += mul;
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the formula for geometric series:

```
Sum[i = k..k+n](a^i) = (a^k - a^(k+n+1)) / (1 - a)
                     = a^k * (1 - a^(n+1)) / (1 - a)
```

With this, the implementation can be done in a single `for` loop (or 2 simple `for` loop): either with O(n) simple looping, or with O(log n) [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

However, the drawback is that the data type must be able to hold at least `(1 - a^(n+1))`, while summing up normally only requires the result to fit in the data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single loop which is O(N) instead of nested loops which is O(N^2)

```
long total = 1, power = m
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){   
    total += power;
    power *= m;
}
System.out.print(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
temp=1;
for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
    temp *= m;
}
total += temp;
}
System.out.println(total+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily calculate powers using your own `pow` function, something like:

```
private static long power(int a, int b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Negative powers not supported.");
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (b == 1) {
        return a;
    }
    return a * power(a, b - 1);
}
```

Then simply loop over all the values and add them up:

```
long out = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    out += power(m, i);
}
System.out.println(out);
```

I would add that this is a classic dynamic programming problem as `m^n` is `m * m^(n-1)`. I would therefore add caching of previously calculated powers so that you don't have to recalculate.

```
private static Map<Integer, Long> powers;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int m = 4;
    int n = 4;
    powers = new HashMap<>();
    long out = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        out += power(m, i);
    }
    System.out.println(out);
    System.out.println(powers);
}

private static long power(int a, int b) {
    if (b < 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Negative powers not supported.");
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (b == 1) {
        return a;
    }
    Long power = powers.get(b);
    if (power == null) {
        power = a * power(a, b - 1);
        powers.put(b, power);
    }
    return power;
}
```

This caches calculated values so that you only calculate the *next* multiple each time.